# Создание ячеек для игры "Сапер" на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не знаю как создать ячейки для сапера в html/css/javascript. С помощью div'ов или как? Мне не хватает знаний для этого.

Comment: Создайте таблицу из `n` строк и `m` столбцов.

Comment: хороша была бы конкретная реализация. Для сапера нужно пронумеровать их как-то, чтобы потом оперировать ими

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем их нумеровать? У них есть координаты: вертикальный и горизoнтальный индексы.

```js
$("#field").append("<tr/><tr/><tr/><tr/><tr/>")
.find("tr").append("<td/><td/><td/><td/><td/>");
```

```css
td {
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 id="field"></table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @FischerBenkovscki На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо вам также!

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам почти половина игры «Сапёр» на чистом JS без использования каких-либо библиотек:

```js
//Заполнение минами. Такое заполнение для игры не подойдёт, его надо усовершенствовать:
var mineField = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  mineField[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 50 + 30).toString(2).slice(0,5).split('');

/* ДЛЯ ПРИМЕРА mineField будет примерно таким:
1 - мина, 0 - пустая клетка
var mineField =
[
 ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1'],
 ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
];
*/

for(var y = 0; y < 5; y++)
{
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 document.getElementById('mine-field').appendChild(tr);
 for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
 {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.align = 'center';
  td.valign = 'middle';
  td.x = x; td.y = y;
  td.innerHTML = '<a>&#x2715;</a>';
  td.onclick = function()
  {
   //плюс стоит для преобразования в integer:
   if(+mineField[this.y][this.x])
   {
    this.innerHTML = '<a>&#x1f4a3;</a>';
    // Ваш код: если нажато на мину
   }
   else
   {
    this.innerHTML = '<a></a>';
    //Ваш код: если нажато на пустую клетку и клетку возле мины
   }
  };
  tr.appendChild(td);
 }
}
```

```css
#mine-field td{width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer}
#mine-field td a{color: blue}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="mine-field"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать через тег TABLE, а там можно через тег A в каждой ячейке.
Если ты имеешь ввиду самому вписывать кол-во ячеек, то это можно через php

Comment: Спасибо но я не знаю php